# Enviar dados de um jQuery para o controlador

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel-8

Olá, pessoal.
Estou com um problema no meu código, já tentei verificar outras perguntas aqui mas não consegui identificar meu problema, acredito que seja algo simples, pois estou iniciando em JS, jQuery e PHP.
Mas vamos ao problema, quando envio dados do jQuery para o controlador, as informações não estão sendo emitidas, já tentei de tudo e não consegui identificar.
Antes de serem enviadas, utilizei o console.log e verifiquei que no jQuery está funcionando, mas ao receber no controlador, a variável $request vem vazia. O que estou fazendo de errado?
Segue meu código:

HTML - Index

```
@extends('layout')

@section('cabecalho')
    <div class="justify-content-center mb-6 " id="cabecalho">
        <br>Consulte a data de Vacinação contra o Coronavírus<br><br>
    </div>   
@endsection

@section('conteudo')

    <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <div class="card me-3 container-fluid" style="width: 35rem;">
            <div class="card-body" id="card1">
                <div class="alert alert-primary" align="center" id="cardSegundaDose">
                    <br><strong><h2>
                        SEGUNDA DOSE
                    </h2></strong><br>
                </div> 

                <form name="segundaDose" id="segundaDose">  
                    <center>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('images/ampola_vacina.jpg') }}"  alt="Ampola Vacina" width="200" height="200">
                    </center>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="select form-group col-6">
                            <label for="marcaVacina" class="mb-3 mt-3">Qual a vacina tomada:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="marcaVacina" id="marcaVacina">
                                <option selected value="null">Selecione uma Opção</option>
                                <option value="AztraZeneca">AztraZeneca</option>
                                <option value="Coronavac">Coronavac</option>
                                <option value="Jansen">Jansen - Reforço</option>
                                <option value="Pfizer">Pfizer</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        
                        <div class="row col-5">
                            <label class="mb-3 mt-3" for="primeiraDose">Data da 1ª Dose:</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control text-center col-6" name="primeiraDose" id="primeiraDose" placeholder="Formato dd/mm/aaaa">
                        </div>
                        

                        <div class="mt-3 text-center">
                            <input type="submit" form="segundaDose" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Consultar">
                        </div>

                        <div name="respostaCalculo" id="respostaCalculo"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        {{--     
            INÍCIO DO CARD DA TERCEIRA DOSE
        --}}

        <div class="card container-fluid" style="width: 35rem;">
            <div class="card-body">    
                <div class="alert alert-warning mb-3" align="center" id="cardTerceiraDose">
                    <br><strong><h2>
                        TERCEIRA DOSE
                    </h2></strong><br>
                </div> 

                <form name="terceiraDose" id="terceiraDose">
                    <center>
                        <img src="{{ asset('images/ampola_vacina.jpg') }}" alt="Ampola Vacina" width="200" height="200">
                    </center>

                    <div class="form-group row">    
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <label class="mb-3 mt-3" for="dataSegundaDose">Data da 2ª Dose:</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control text-center col-6" name="dataSegundaDose" id="dataSegundaDose" placeholder="Formato dd/mm/aaaa">
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="mt-3 text-center">
                            <input type="submit" form="terceiraDose" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" value="Consultar">
                        </div>

                        <div name="respostaTerceiraDose" id="respostaTerceiraDose" type="date"></div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {{-- Chamada dos scripts que serão utilizados para atualizar com as informações das próximas vacinas --}}
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jQuery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>

@endsection
```

**Script JS**

```
// -- SEGUNDA DOSE  --
//Função que paga os dados do form, enviam para o controller e 
//devolvem para impressão na tela da próxima data para vacinação

$('#segundaDose').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#respostaCalculo').html('');

    var dataForm = $('#segundaDose').serialize();
    var data = $('#primeiraDose').val();

    var isValidDate = function(data) {
        return !!new Date(data).getTime();
    }
    if(isValidDate(data) === false){
        return alert("A data informada não é válida!");
    }

    getCalculoSegundaDose(dataForm);
});

function getCalculoSegundaDose(dataForm) {

    var url = window.location;

    $.ajax({
        url: url.origin+'/segundaDose', 
        type: 'GET',
        data: dataForm,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            var data = result.data.split('-').reverse().join('/');
            var resultado = result.resultado.replace(/-/g, "/");

            $('#respostaCalculo').prepend('<div class="alert alert-info mt-2" align="center" role="alert">Como você tomou a primeira dose em <strong>' + data + '</strong>,<br><strong>você poderá tomar a segunda dose da ' + result.vacina +' a partir de ' + resultado +  '. </strong></div>');
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#respostaCalculo').prepend('<div class="alert alert-warning mt-2 alignb="center">Não foi possível realizar o cálculo, por favor, tente novamente fornecendo a Vacina e Data da Vacinação.</div>');
        }
    });
}


// -- TERCEIRA DOSE  --

$('#terceiraDose').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#respostaTerceiraDose').html('');

    var dataForm1 = $('#terceiraDose').serialize();
    var data2Dose = $('#dataSegundaDose').val();

    var isValidDate = function(data2Dose) {
        return !!new Date(data2Dose).getTime();
    }
    if(isValidDate(data2Dose) === false){
        return alert("A data informada não é válida!");
    }

    getCalculoTerceiraDose(dataForm1);

});

function getCalculoTerceiraDose(dataForm1){

    var url = window.location;    

    $.ajax({
        url: url.origin+'/terceiraDose',
        type: 'GET',
        data: dataForm1,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            var data = result.data.split('-').reverse().join('/');
            var resultado = result.resultado.replace(/-/g, "/");
            var resultadoImuno = result.resultadoImuno.replace(/-/g, "/");

            $('#respostaTerceiraDose').prepend('<div class="alert alert-info mt-2" align="center" role="alert">Como você tomou a segunda dose em <strong> ' + data + ' </strong>,<br><strong>você poderá tomar a terceira dose a partir de ' + resultado +  '. Porém, caso seja paciente imunossuprimido, poderá tomar a terceira dose a partir de ' + resultadoImuno + '.</strong></div>');
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#respostaTerceiraDose').prepend('<div class="alert alert-warning mt-2 alignb="center">Não foi possível realizar o cálculo, por favor, tente novamente fornecendo a data da segunda dose.</div>');
        }
    });
}
```

**As função do controller onde o JS envia os dados:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\TerceiraDoseRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CalculadoraController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('calculadora.index');
    }

    public function segundaDose(Request $request)
    {
        $vacina = $request->marcaVacina;
        $data = $request->primeiraDose;
        
        //Dias de espera para tomar a segunda dose de acordo com cada vacina.
        $astraZeneca = 56;
        $coronavac = 28;
        $jansenReforco = 61;
        $pfizer = 56;

        // Este switch/case verifica qual vacina foi a selecionada, chama o método calcularSegundaDose e atribui
        // os dias que precisam para calcular a data da terceira dose.
        if($data != 'null' && $vacina != 'null'){
            switch ($vacina) {
                case 'AztraZeneca':
                    $segundaDose = $this->calcularSegundaDose($astraZeneca, $data);
                    $status = true;
                    break;

                case 'Coronavac':
                    $segundaDose = $this->calcularSegundaDose($coronavac, $data);
                    $status = true;
                    break;

                case 'Jansen':
                    $segundaDose = $this->calcularSegundaDose($jansenReforco, $data);
                    $status = true;
                    break;

                case 'Pfizer':
                    $segundaDose = $this->calcularSegundaDose($pfizer, $data);
                    $status = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    $segundaDose = 'Por favor, selecione uma das vacinas liberadas.';
                    $status = false;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return json_encode(['resultado' => $segundaDose, 'vacina' => $vacina, 'data' => $data, 'status' => $status]);        
    }

    public function calcularSegundaDose(int $vacina, string $datainicio)
    {
        ini_set('date.timezone','America/Sao_Paulo');
        $datatermino = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+".$vacina."days", strtotime($datainicio)));

        return $datatermino;
    }

    public function terceiraDose(Request $request)
    {
        $prazo = 120;
        $prazoImuno = 28;
        $data = $request->dataSegundaDose;

        // // Neste echo é possível verificar que os dados do $request estão vazios.
        // echo 'Data: '.$request->dataSegundaDose.'<br>Prazo: '.$prazo . '<br>Prazo Imuno:' . $prazoImuno;
        // exit();
        
        // Aparentemente, o $data está vindo com valor null, o que acaba gerando erro no cálculo.

        ini_set('date.timezone','America/Sao_Paulo');
        $dataTerceiraDose = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+".$prazo."days", strtotime($data)));
        $dataTerceiraDoseImuno = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+".$prazoImuno."days", strtotime($data)));

        return json_encode(['resultado' => $dataTerceiraDose, 'resultadoImuno' => $dataTerceiraDoseImuno, 'data' => $data]);
    }

}
```

**E pra finalizar, minha rota**

```
Route::get('calculadora', [CalculadoraController::class, 'index'])->name('calculadora_index');
Route::get('segundaDose', [CalculadoraController::class, 'segundaDose'])->name('segundaDose');
Route::get('terceiraDose', [CalculadoraController::class, 'terceiraDose'])->name('terceiraDose');
```

Estou usando o Laravel 8, PHP 8.0 e jQuery 3.6 pra fazer este projeto. Fiz uma função semelhante à esta #terceiraDose que funcionou perfeitamente. Não consigo identificar onde está o problema.

**EDIT:** Conforme recomendado, alterei o método de envio do ajax para post, porém continuou o problema, apresentando o erro:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/calculadora 405 (Method Not Allowed)
send @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
getCalculoTerceiraDose @ script.js:44
(anônimo) @ script.js:33
dispatch @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
```

O que acho mais estranho, é que no arquivo **script.js** tem o processo #segundaDose, que chama a função **getCalculoSegundaDose** que está funcionando perfeitamente, mesmo com o método get.
Não consigo entender qual o motivo das informações não serem recebidas pelo CalculadoraController, para realização dos cálculos.

**Edit. 2:** Fiz algumas alterações no código e o método voltou a funcionar. Atualizei os códigos acima com as versões corretas, caso alguém precise destas informações. Agora o sistema funciona normalmente.
Mesmo sendo algo simples, me deu bastante dor de cabeça, mas ser iniciante em dev é isso.

De qualquer forma, agradeço pela ajuda. O Tópico pode ser fechado.

Answer (score 0):

Algumas mudanças que eu faria no seu código seria mudar JS para Post assim como a Rota

```
$.ajax({
    ur: url.origin+'/terceiraDose',
    type: 'POST',
    data: dataForm1,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        $('#respostaTerceiraDose').prepend('<div class="alert alert-info mt-2" align="center" role="alert">Como você tomou a segunda dose em <strong> ' + result.data + ' </strong>,<br><strong>você poderá tomar a terceira dose a partir de ' + result.resultado +  '. </strong></div>');
    },
    error: function(result){
        //$('#respostaTerceiraDose').prepend('<div> ' + result.data + ' - ' + result.resultado + ' </div>');
        $('#respostaTerceiraDose').prepend('<div class="alert alert-warning mt-2 alignb="center">Não foi possível realizar o cálculo, por favor, tente novamente fornecendo a Vacina e Data da Vacinação.</div>');
    }
});
```

Também criaria um Request para validar os campos

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class TerceiraDoseRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'nome' => 'required|max:255',
            'telefone' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
            'mensagem' => 'required'
        ];


        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Então mudaria no Controller o tipo de Request para o criado

```
public function terceiraDose(TerceiraDoseRequest $request)
```

Comment: Tentei rodar o programa com as atualizações que você recomendou, mas ainda não resolveu. Novamente, o jQuery recebe o valor informado, mas não envia ao controlador. Também deu o erro: `POST http://localhost:8000/calculadora 405 (Method Not Allowed)`. Vou editar a pergunta e adicionar o código completo das classes. @Jonathan Halberstadt